# Is the character of Mirasta Yale from TNG episode "First Contact" ever revisited?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

First off, this is not a question about the movie *First Contact*.  It is a question about the eponymous episode from Season 4 of *TNG*.

In that episode, Riker is wounded on Malcor III, where he is posing as a Malcorian. Malcor III was on the verge of warp capability and Riker was collecting data in order to help assess the impact that first contact might have.  Riker's injury and capture forces Picard to reveal himself to the Malcorians slightly ahead of schedule.

Picard's main contact on Malcor III is Space Administrator Mirasta Yale.  She advocates for Picard and Riker's good intentions, and convinces the Malcorian Chancellor to give Picard Riker's whereabouts.

Eventually, the Chancellor decides to postpone relations indefinitely with the Federation.  Having seen all that she has seen, Mirasta is unwilling to return to Malcor III and the Chancellor gives her permission to stay off-world.  Picard orders Worf to assign her quarters.  That is the last we see of her, to my knowledge.

**Do we hear of Mirasta again?  If not in the official universe, then how about in the extended universe?  In particular, does she remain on the Enterprise?**

Comment: I've often thought that a story following Mirasta's assimilation into the federation could have been interesting.

Comment: I always thought she should end up with Tom Riker.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nope. There are no further references to Mirasta Yale in any TV shows, EU novels or other media.

The only glancing reference I've been able to find is in the [Official novelisation](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/77082.All_Good_Things_) of the episode [TNG : All Good Things](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_Good_Things..._%28Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation%29) which identifies the transporter operator on the USS Pasteur as a Malcorian female.

> And before he had to put up with any further protests, he found
>   himself somewhere else entirely. It took him a heartbeat to realize
>   that he had materialized on one of the Pasteur's transporter
>   platforms.
>
> "Welcome aboard," said the transporter operator—**a slender Malcorian
>   female with long red hair twisted into a braid.**

Given that the episode is set approximately 28 years after the events of TNG : First Contact, we're left with the possibilities that Malcor have entered the Federation (unlikely), that this is another Malcorian exile (unlikely) or that this is the child of Mirasta Yale (likely).

Comment: The likely or unlikely Ness of each possibility is pure speculating

Comment: @cde - I've based that on the events of the episode. If they were planning to shelve their warp programme it seems highly unlikely that just 28 years later they would have members of their race in Starfleet (or even that there would be more exiles). The fact that there's a only one Malcorian in the entire  Federation would suggest that other Malcorians are probably related to her. Yes, speculation but not without logical basis.

Comment: Then she would at best be a hybrid and not described as Malcorian. Governments change hands and policies change quickly.  28 years is a long time.

Comment: @cde - hence likely/unlikely rather than possible/impossible. Is it more likely that the Malcorian seen is her child or more likely that Malcor has abandoned its policy of introversion sufficiently to not only enter the Federation but to also have their officers serving on Federation vessels?

Comment: @Richard:   Why is everyone assuming this has to be Mirasta Yale's child?   It could be Yale herself.   28 years is not an unusual amount of time for her to (1) catch up on all the technology, science and math -- remember she would basically have to go back to high school level, (2) attend the academy, and then (3) get a posting on the Pasteur.    Not everyone is a superstar who makes Commander in 8 years (or Captain in a day according to ST2009).

Comment: @ThePopMachine - True, but she doesn't fit the description; Not natably slender, not especially red-headed; http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/File:Mirasta_Yale.jpg

Comment: @Richard: I did have the impression she is redheaded -- I think the captures just don't show it.   I also don't think the description of slender is inappropriate.   But anyways 28 years, hair dye, diets, and we don't know anything about Malcorian physiology or aging.  Compare that to the assumption that Malcorians can even bear children with non-Malcorians, that the offspring would be described as "Malcorian".   Or that they can reproduce asexually?  I mean, all things things certainly aren't MORE likely than just that it's her.   You're giving three options and assigning likeliness to them.

Comment: ... and there are certainly other options.   Not the least of which is that it's just her.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - Thematically, it makes more sense to me that it's her child. You're right of course that we don't know if Malcorians change hair colour as the age, live unnaturally long, etc

Comment: @Richard:   Maybe she just really looks up to her captain.